# Selenium having issues running on mac. Error unexpected argument service

Tags: python, macos, selenium

This code works fine on windows but on mac it gives me this error.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/shh/Desktop/gen/app.py", line 467, in worker
    account(item, password)
  File "/Users/shh/Desktop/gen/app.py", line 159, in account
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by removing the service option and just adding path to the chromedriver.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```